# How to break the game when it reaches the score 10?

Tags: python

I'm working on Rock, Paper, Scissor game and I want to break the game when the score reaches 10(points) but I'm unable to do it. Can anyone tell me how to do that. I have used while loop for that but I can't get the actual output that I need.

And what this stands for?

```
#elif((player_input[1] - computer_input[1]) % 3 == 1):
```

```
player_score = 0

computer_score = 0

options = [('rock',0), ('paper',1), ('scissors',2)]

def player_choice(player_input):

    global player_score, computer_score

    computer_input = get_computer_choice()

    player_choice_label.config(text = 'You Selected : ' + player_input[0])

    computer_choice_label.config(text = 'Computer Selected : ' + computer_input[0])

    if(player_input == computer_input):

        winner_label.config(text = "Tie")

    elif((player_input[1] - computer_input[1]) % 3 == 1):

        player_score += 1

        winner_label.config(text="You Won!!!")

        player_score_label.config(text = 'Your Score : ' + str(player_score))

    else:
        computer_score += 1

        winner_label.config(text="Computer Won!!!")

        computer_score_label.config(text='Computer Score : ' + str(computer_score))

#Function to Randomly Select Computer Choice
def get_computer_choice():

    return random.choice(options)
```

Comment: Please don't spam unrelated tags.

Comment: Also please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922).

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do to declare a winner and exit the game when it reaches 10 score:

```
import time

player_score = 0
computer_score = 0
options = [('rock',0), ('paper',1), ('scissors',2)]

def player_choice(player_input):

    global player_score, computer_score

    ###### Check if the score reached 10 already.######

    if computer_score == 10 or player_score == 10:
        time.sleep(2)
        exit(0)

    computer_input = get_computer_choice()

    player_choice_label.config(text = 'Your Selected : ' + player_input[0])
    computer_choice_label.config(text = 'Computer Selected : ' + computer_input[0])

    if(player_input == computer_input):
        winner_label.config(text = "Tie")
    elif((player_input[1] - computer_input[1]) % 3 == 1):
        player_score += 1

        ###### Declare the winner when current score is 10 #######

        if player_score == 10:
            winner_label.config(text="You Won the GAME!!!")
            player_score_label.config(text='Your Score : ' + str(player_score))

        else:
            winner_label.config(text="You Won!!!")
            player_score_label.config(text = 'Your Score : ' + str(player_score))
    else:
        computer_score += 1

        ###### Declare the winner when current score is 10 #######

        if computer_score == 10:
            winner_label.config(text="Computer Won the GAME!!!")
            computer_score_label.config(text='Your Score : ' + str(computer_score))

        else:
            winner_label.config(text="Computer Won!!!")
            computer_score_label.config(text='Your Score : ' + str(computer_score))

#Function to Randomly Select Computer Choice
def get_computer_choice():
    return random.choice(options)
```

Now what `#elif((player_input[1] - computer_input[1]) % 3 == 1):` does is:
When you enter **Rock**, your input is considered as `0` now if the computer enters **Scissors** it will be considered `2`. So `player_input[1]-computer_input[1]` would be **0-2 = -2**. Now -2%3 will give `1` because the formula for modulo is: `a%b = a-b(a//b)`. So for each instance where player will win are:

```
Rock 0 Scissor 2 -> (0-2)%3 = -2-3*(-2//3) = 1
Paper 1 Rock 0 -> (-1-0)%3 = -1-3*(-1//3) = 1
Scissor 2 Paper 1 -> (2-1)%3 = 1-3*(1//3) = 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and quick reply. It worked me.

Comment: Hey it would be really helpful to me as well if you will upvote and accept the answer.